# Как вы ставите ударение в наречии "одновременно"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как известно, в слове "одновременно" разрешены **оба варианта.** Носители языка выбирают **по ситуации**, но как именно? Скорее всего, и вовсе не задумываются об этом. А если  спросить, то какой будет ответ? Возможно, какие-то **смысловые оттенки**  учитываются.

**И вопрос:** Как вы ставите ударение в приведенных предложениях:

(1) *Трилогия получилась вразброс — можно и хвалить, и ругать **одновременно**.*

(2) Это был последний фильм, где звук и видеоряд записывался **одновременно** и вживую!

(3) Как сейчас помню: я металась по кухне, потому что у меня **одновременно** горел лук и убегал суп, и тут зазвонил телефон...

(4) Это дает возможность **одновременно** получать доступ к нескольким вариантам бюджета, анализировать и сравнивать данные.

(5) Владение антикварными предметами становится **одновременно** как желанным, так и подозрительным, опасным.

Я ставлю разное ударение в соотношении 3 и 2.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Смещение** ударения с основы на **суффикс или окончание** в относительных прилагательных — интересная тема. Там много **парных** вариантов: переносный и переносной, переводный и переводной, харАктерный и характЕрный, языковый и языковой.

Если ударение остается **на основе**, то мы подчеркиваем **связь с существительным**, в других же случаях могут появляться **новые значения**. Эту тенденцию интересно посмотреть на примере наречия ***"одновременно".***

Я разделила предложения **на две группы**: два предложения и три предложения, причем учитывала **семантическую** разницу, что проявлялось и в разном ударении.

Comment: Как понять 3 и 2? Т.е 3 ударения на оди слог, 2 на другой?  1,2,4,5 на последний слог, 3 на третий. Я ставлю ударение, не задумываясь.

Comment: Нет, это не про слоги.  Два предложения и три предложения – в них разное решение.  Я тоже не задумывалась, как и все, а потом решила приглядеться. Мне показалось, что я оба варианта использую. Посмотрела в Нацкорпусе, нашла эти примеры  - да действительно, разница есть. Еще интересно в толковом словаре посмотреть  https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=одновременно&mode=slovari&dicts[]=42  Там два значения указано.

Comment: Я не выбираю ударения в зависимости от значения. Все получается механически.

Comment: Я ставлю на вторую Е. А у вас на первую в 1-м и 3-м?

Comment: Нет, не совсем. Из всех примеров я по семантике выделила два предложения, у них есть особые признаки. Первый вариант вошел в эту  группу. Попробуйте поискать эти признаки.

Comment: А какой вариант первый?

Comment: В 1-м предложении у меня смещение ударения на ЕНН.

Comment: С глаголами небось: одновремЕнно горел и ругать одновремЕнно. А остальные одноврЕменно, aren't they?

Comment: Мне больше нравится с ударением на второе Е: _одновремéнно_. Кому как, но варианты на 100 % равноправны, как варианты _матрас_ и _матрац_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только с предлогом *со-* наречие ударяется на вторую *Е*: *совремéнно*. Также, если «проблемное» *одновременно* (особенно в живой речи) легко заменить на *сразу*, ударение может смещаться на вторую *Е* (первая и пятая фразы вполне подходят).

С предлогом *без-* и в сложных словах — на первую *Е*. Безударными остаются предшествующие части: безврéменно, преждеврéменно, заблаговрéменно...

В словари и Грамоту не заглядывал. Нет смысла: приучил себя ударять *одновременно* только на первую. Позже посмотрю.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Вы из 5 предложений можете выделит два по семантике? Им я "назначила" особое ударение.

Comment: Для *хвалить* и *ругать*, *желанным* и *подозрительным* — одновремéнно. Здесь крайности на весах. Хотя даже при таких подрробностях не отходил бы от нормы. Не припомню слов с плавающим ударением. Разве что неопределившаяся «Украина».

Comment: Но ведь два ударения – это норма и есть. Это означает, что носители в раной мере пользуются обоими вариантами.

Comment: Вы не могли бы записать ваш окончательный ответ с номерами предложений?

Answer (score 1):

Как? - одновремЕнно - о связанных событиях, единовременно, о разных обстоятельствах приведших к совместному исходу.

Когда? - одноврЕменно, в одно и тоже время, но разные несвязанные события.

Из пункта А в пункт Б одноврЕменно выехали два автомобиля с разными скоростями(дано), а из пункта Б в пункт А одновремЕнно с ними выехала мотоцикл, который встретил автомобили на расстоянии 1 и 2 от А соответственно, найти скорость мотоцикла...

(1) Трилогия получилась вразброс — можно и хвалить, и ругать одновремЕнно.

(2) Это был последний фильм, где звук и видеоряд записывал**ись** одноврЕменно и вживую!

(3) Как сейчас помню: я металась по кухне, потому что у меня одноврЕменно/одновремЕнно горел лук и убегал суп, и тут зазвонил телефон... - можно оба варианта.

Выбор зависит от: металась одновремЕнно с тем, что горели / или горело и убегало одноврЕменно.

Относительно пунктуации.

Как сейчас помню: я металась по кухне, потому что у меня, одновремЕнно, горел лук и убегал суп - и тут зазвонил телефон...

Как сейчас помню: я металась по кухне, потому что у меня одноврЕменно горел лук и убегал суп - и тут зазвонил телефон...

Хотяя, если прямо там запятая, то наверное, всё прямо нейтрально так:

Как сейчас помню: я металась по кухне, потому что у меня одноврЕменно горел лук и убегал суп, и тут зазвонил телефон...

(4) Это дает возможность одновременно получать доступ к нескольким вариантам бюджета, анализировать и сравнивать данные. - тоже можно оба варианта. Это - даёт возможность одновремЕнно / или ... - одноврЕменно получать. Если бы было И получать, И анализировать, тогда одновремЕнно.

(5) Владение антикварными предметами становится одновремЕнно как желанным, так и подозрительным, опасным.

Comment: Может быть, но вы мне ответ дайте по пяти предложениям. Как в передаче «Что? Где? Когда?».

Comment: @Sharon добавил. Во 2 синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: Пжста, определитесь точно с ударением, сделайте окончательный выбор.  Я сказала: разбейте на две группы. Что же еще-то?

Comment: @Sharon а я не определился? Ну с 3 мб пока не определся)

Comment: В 3-м и 4-м какое ударение?

Comment: *Шарон, я мимо?*

Comment: @Sharon в 4 есть два варианта прочтения. И в третьем тоже.

Comment: А вы выберите один. Прочтите, как вам нравится. А то ваша минута уже проходит.

Comment: Артем, нет, один не совпадает.

Comment: @Sharon я добавил бреда - смотрите)

Comment: Так мне ответ нужен! Однозначный!  Как разделить на две группы?  Скажите уж коротко.  В передаче нет объяснений, есть только правильный ответ от задающего вопрос.

Comment: @Sharon 2, речевая+1,1, оба(тут вряд ли я определюсь - возможность получать или возможность одновременно получать), 2

Comment: Не по правилам играете.  Примерно выберите.  Что-нибудь.

Comment: @Sharon ладно, пусть 1. Но 4 прям с подвохом каким-то.

Comment: Что 1? Поточнее скажите.  ОдновремЕнно - номера предложений, одноврЕменно - номера предложений.

Comment: ОдновремЕнно - 1,5, одноврЕменно -2,3,4

Comment: Это ваш окончательный ответ?  На поле еще один участник.

Comment: хахаха))) окончательный!

Comment: Сейчас спрошу у другого))

Comment: У первого участника вроде бы такие же ответы, но он их раньше дал.  Вам спасибо за участие.

Answer (score 1):

*Судя по всему, вы произносите так:*

(1) Трилогия получилась вразброс — можно и хвалить, и ругать одноврем**е**нно.

(2) Это был последний фильм, где звук и видеоряд записывался одноврем**е**нно и вживую!

(3) Как сейчас помню: я металась по кухне, потому что у меня одноврем**е**нно горел лук и убегал суп, и тут зазвонил телефон...

(4) Это дает возможность одновр**е**менно получать доступ к нескольким вариантам бюджета, анализировать и сравнивать данные.

(5) Владение антикварными предметами становится одновр**е**менно как желанным, так и подозрительным, опасным.

Comment: Спасибо, Артем, за ответ.  У меня не такие варианты. Но это не так важно). Голос за участие.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ

**ОдновремЕнный — 1 и 5, одноврЕменный — 2, 3, 4.**

Пояснение

ОДНОВРЕМЕННО; нареч. 1. к **Одновременный**. Невозможно работать и о. отвечать на телефонные звонки! Мы с вами пришли почти о. 2. **В равной мере.** Он человек **серьёзный** и о. **легкомысленный**. Держался **заискивающе** и о. **развязно.** Было тихо, по-домашнему и о. напряжённо. В ней есть что-то **притягательное** и о. **отталкивающее.**

Я думаю, что **новый** оттенок значения - это **в равной мере**, поэтому  надо ориентироваться на противоположности:

(1) Трилогия получилась вразброс — можно **и хвалить, и ругать** одновременно.

(5) Владение антикварными предметами становится одновременно **как желанным, так и подозрительным,** опасным.